# Running Django function every n insert to a specific model

Tags: django, django-models

Is there a way to run a piece of code in Django when say 128 new entries are made to a specific model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yeah that can be done using signals in django, you can use this logic in a signals.py file or in your models.py, then remove the import of MyModel if using is models.py file

```
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from myapp.models import MyModel


@receiver(post_save, sender=MyModel)
def my_handler(sender, **kwargs):
    total = MyModel.objects.count() //this will return total number of rows
    if total % 128 == 0:
       do what you want to do
```

Comment: i am ok with this answer but:
If user delete and add again this will have issue (about count). So depend on the purpose he should use .count() or get the latest id (to check about how many time, instate of how many row)

Comment: if any row is deleted then on adding of new row it will return the old count +1, so there is nothing like an issue, this will only be triggered when a new column is added

Comment: I think it should be `total % 128 == 0:` as described in the question, to do something for every new 128 entries.

Comment: What if I want count by the number of objects with the same foreign key group as the saved object. Say I save a article under a specific category and I want to perform an action every 128 article inserted into each category.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a signal handler for that model post_save ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/signals/#post-save)). Then, if the `created` argument is `True`, increment a counter. If the counter reaches 0 modulo 128, then call your function.